# Getting PhysicalDrive using Drive Letter?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to call an command line application which requires block level access to a raw disk to operate (`qemu`) using a batch script to help people in the field test cloned flash drives without risk to their equipment.

I know I can use `wmic diskdrive list brief` to get the `PhysicalDrive` number of the disks attached to the system, and I can use `"%CD:~0,2%"` to get the drive letter of the current drive. I also know that `wmic logicaldisk list brief` to grab the list of drives by letter.

The two lists *should* correlate, but I can't guarantee that they do - and there are no two fields that seem persistent across the two modes of data output - is there a good way to guarantee I pass the correct drive to `qemu`?

For reference, the resulting `qemu` command needs to only be this:

`qemu -hda \\.\PhysicalDrive#` where "#" is the drive number of the drive the script is executing from.

Comment: It is not as simple as you might think :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could try the accompanying [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), which uses [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) like this:

```bat
@For /F Tokens^=2Delims^=^" %%A In ('WMIC LogicalDisk Where "DeviceID='%~d0'" Assoc /AssocClass:Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition 2^>Nul^|Find "n."')Do @For /F Tokens^=2Delims^=^" %%B In ('WMIC Path Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition 2^>Nul^|Find "%%A"')Do @QEmu -hda %%B
```

This is the same line but split over `4` lines, for easier reading, *but needs no adjustment to run it*:

```bat
@For /F Tokens^=2Delims^=^" %%A In ('WMIC LogicalDisk Where "DeviceID='%~d0'"^
 Assoc /AssocClass:Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition 2^>Nul^|Find "n."'
)Do @For /F Tokens^=2Delims^=^" %%B In ('WMIC Path^
 Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition 2^>Nul^|Find "%%A"')Do @QEmu -hda %%B
```

*The code examples above use `%~d0` as the drive letter holding the running batch file. If you wanted the drive for the current directory instead, (because this will not necessarily be the same), replace `%~d0` with `%CD:~,2%`.*

Comment: This is perfect!
I should have realized through the documentation pages for `WMIC` that I could use arbitrary windows classes in this manner, rather than limiting myself to the default parameters available via `wmic logicaldisk` and `wmic diskdrive`
This is a very elegant solution to the problem, and I think using `%~d0` instead of `%CD:~,2%` is probably more sane in the end, as it makes it possible to package this script and run it as part of the USB drive build process without worry of calling Qemu on the wrong device and resulting in frustration. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GarrettStewart, thank you for your feedback, I'm happy that my code was useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a powershell script.. as you can see it is not a matter of just writing 2 lines of code.

```
Function Main {
    $diskdrives = get-wmiobject Win32_DiskDrive | sort Index
    $colSize = @{Name='Size';Expression={Get-HRSize $_.Size}}
    foreach ( $disk in $diskdrives ) {
        $scsi_details = 'SCSI ' + $disk.SCSIBus         + ':' +
                                  $disk.SCSILogicalUnit + ':' +
                                  $disk.SCSIPort        + ':' +
                                  $disk.SCSITargetID
        write $( 'Disk ' + $disk.Index + ' - ' + $scsi_details +
                 ' - ' + ( Get-HRSize $disk.size) )
        $part_query = 'ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="' +
                      $disk.DeviceID.replace('\','\\') +
                      '"} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition'
        $partitions = @( get-wmiobject -query $part_query | 
                         sort StartingOffset )
        foreach ($partition in $partitions) {
            $vol_query = 'ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="' +
                         $partition.DeviceID +
                         '"} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition'
            $volumes   = @(get-wmiobject -query $vol_query)
            write $( '    Partition ' + $partition.Index + '  ' +
                     ( Get-HRSize $partition.Size) + '  ' +
                     $partition.Type
                   )

            foreach ( $volume in $volumes) {
                write $( '        ' + $volume.name  +
                        ' [' + $volume.FileSystem + '] ' + 
                         ( Get-HRSize $volume.Size ) + ' ( ' +
                         ( Get-HRSize $volume.FreeSpace ) + ' free )'
                       )
            }
        }
        write ''
    }
}

function Get-HRSize {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [INT64] $bytes
    )
    process {
        if     ( $bytes -gt 1pb ) { "{0:N2} PB" -f ($bytes / 1pb) }
        elseif ( $bytes -gt 1tb ) { "{0:N2} TB" -f ($bytes / 1tb) }
        elseif ( $bytes -gt 1gb ) { "{0:N2} GB" -f ($bytes / 1gb) }
        elseif ( $bytes -gt 1mb ) { "{0:N2} MB" -f ($bytes / 1mb) }
        elseif ( $bytes -gt 1kb ) { "{0:N2} KB" -f ($bytes / 1kb) }
        else   { "{0:N} Bytes" -f $bytes }
    }
} 
Main
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe how much more complicated Windows automation tasks can be than Linux for something so small. This script is fantastic, but Powershell isn't available all the time, sadly.